# Facing Wierd Issue using pandas-0.24.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am using python/pandas on Windows 10 from last month & did not face the below issue that suddenly came into being. I have a csv file that is read with pandas. However, the dataframe is arbitrarily joining the comma separated heading into one & while doing this abruptly leaving off last few characters, as a result of this, the code though very simple, is failing. Has anyone seen this kind of problem? Suggestions to overcome this would be of great help

Was trying to check the date format to be in 'yyyy-mm-dd'. Since I got the error, put a print statement to check column names,
Reinstalled python 3.6.8, pandas etc, but that did not help.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Data.csv','r')

print(df.columns)
for pdt in df.PublicDate:
    try:
        dat = pdt[0:10]
        if dat[4] != '-' or dat[7] != '-':
            print('\nPub Date Format Error',dat)
    except TypeError as e:
        print(e)
```

Test Data csv file has:

```
PIC,PublicDate,Version,OriginalDate,BPD
ABCD,2019-06-15T19:25:22.000000000Z,1,2019-06-1519.25.22.0000000000,15-06-2019
EFGH,06/15/2019T19:26:22.000000000Z,,2019-06-1519.26.22.0000000000,15-06-2019
IJKL,2019-06-15T20:26:22.000000000Z,1,2019-06-1520.26.22.0000000000,6/25/2019
MNOP,,,2019-06-1520.26.22.0000000000,6/25/2019
QRST,2019-06-15T22:26:22.000000000Z,1,,6/25/2019
```

Expected:

> dates of the format 6/25/2019 should be pointed out for not being in the format 2019-06-25

Actual Result: Below Error

=============== RESTART: H:\Python\DateFormat.py ===============

```
    Index(['PIC,PublicDate,Ve', 'sion,O', 'iginalDate,BPD'], dtype='object')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "H:\Program Files\Python\DateFormat.py", line 8, in <module>
        for pdt in df.PublicDate:
      File "G:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5067, in __getattr__
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
    AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'PublicDate'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the second parameter:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('Data.csv','r')
```

Without it the example works fine:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
```

It happens because the second parameter is separator, not access modifier. With this configuration pandas still available to read the file but cannot create an index or work properly.